# Devexpress GridControl Row Click

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I want to handle **Row Clicked** event when Devexpress grid control row is clicked. Row double click is working like:

```
  <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="RowDoubleClick " 
          Command="{Binding SelectedRowCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentItem, ElementName=grid}" />
  </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

I can't find correct `EventName` for row single click

Comment: Did you try `SelectionChanged` or `FocusedRow`?

Comment: @mm8 `SelectionChanged` works. Thanks and if you put as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle the `SelectionChanged` event to detect when a row is clicked.

Comment: One more thing though. I just noticed `CurrentItem` of `SelectionChanged` is not the newly selected item...

Comment: If you want this, why don't you simply bind the `CurrentItem` property to a source property and handle the logic in the setter of this one?

Comment: I've `ObservableCollection<T>` as `ItemSource` of the grid. Now when clicked, I want `T`

Comment: Yes, I know. So why don't you bind to `CurrentItem`? `CurrentItem="{Binding YourPropertyOfTypeT}"`.